# How can i display Vietnamese characters in a .pdf document using itextsharp?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, utf-8, fonts, itext

I have read a number of threads that discuss this and none have come up with a solution for this problem. Most of them revolve around using a suitable font. I have tried every single one of them with no success. I know this string is UTF-8 and Vietnamese because if i paste it into Notepad++ as an ASCII string and then change encoding to UTF-8 it works.

The input string looks like this;

**"CÃ³ sáºµn dá»‹ch vá»¥ thÃ´ng dá»‹ch miá»…n phÃ­ khi báº¡n yÃªu cáº§u."**

The output string should look like this;

**"Có sẵn dịch vụ thông dịch miễn phí khi bạn yêu cầu."**

My code just produces the first string.
Any help is greatly appreciated. I am tearing my hair out here
Here is my code;

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Module TextToPdf
    Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter
    Dim pdfDoc As Document
    Dim pdfFont As Font
    Sub Main()

        pdfDoc = New Document(PageSize.LETTER)

        pdfFont = New Font(BaseFont.CreateFont(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "vuArial.ttf"), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 15)

        pdfWrite = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("../tmp/vietnamese.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        pdfDoc.Open()
        pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("CÃ³ sáºµn dá»‹ch vá»¥ thÃ´ng dá»‹ch miá»…n phÃ­ khi báº¡n yÃªu cáº§u.", pdfFont))
        pdfDoc.Close()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: *I know this string is UTF-8 and Vietnamese because if i paste it into Notepad++ as an ASCII string and then change encoding to UTF-8 it works.* - no. The string contains characters, not utf-8. What you do in notepad is transform a weird string to bytes using one encoding and transforming them back to characters issuing a different one. You can do the same in java but doing so would be incompetent. Instead use an appropriate encoding for your java files and tell it to your java compiler. Or use **\uXXXX** escapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [probably](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/command-line-compiler/codepage) just save your source code as UTF-8 and paste in the "output" (UTF-8) string, but assuming the source code is ANSI encoding, maybe you can convert it to UTF-8 manually:

```
Dim ansi = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("CÃ³ sáºµn dá»‹ch vá»¥ thÃ´ng dá»‹ch miá»…n phÃ­ khi báº¡n yÃªu cáº§u.")
Dim utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ansi)
pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph(utf8, pdfFont))
```

Comment: Fantastic!! Thanks you so much. I had tried this but i must have implemented it incorrectly.